# CGImage mask doesn't work on Wide Color Gamut displays

Tags: ios, ipad, core-graphics

I have a UIView subclass that renders an image with a mask applied. It works perfectly on all devices (iPad-only) except for those with a Wide Color Gamut display (the newest iPad Pros) where the mask renders completely transparent (it looks to the user like the view isn't there). The relevant init/drawRect code looks like this:

```
init(image: UIImage) {
    scratchable = image.cgImage!
    imageWidth = scratchable.width
    imageHeight = scratchable.height

    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()

    let pixels = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, imageWidth * imageHeight)!

    alphaPixels = CGContext(
        data: CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(pixels),
        width: imageWidth,
        height: imageHeight,
        bitsPerComponent: 8,
        bytesPerRow: imageWidth,
        space: colorspace,
        bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue
    )!
    provider = CGDataProvider(data: pixels)!

    alphaPixels.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)

    let mask = CGImage(
        maskWidth: imageWidth,
        height: imageHeight,
        bitsPerComponent: 8,
        bitsPerPixel: 8,
        bytesPerRow: imageWidth,
        provider: provider,
        decode: nil,
        shouldInterpolate: false
    )!

    scratched = scratchable.masking(mask)!

    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth/2, height: imageHeight/2))

    alphaPixels.fill(imageRect)

    isOpaque = false
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.saveGState()
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: bounds.size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.draw(scratched, in: rect)
    context.restoreGState()
}
```

(For context, the reason `pixels`, `alphaPixels`, etc. are necessary is due to other code in the class that draws into the context to affect the mask).

Any idea why the wide color gamut display would affect this, or what could be done to fix it? I thought it might have something to do with the color space, but the docs clearly state that masks must use `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray` for it to work properly (which is indeed true).

Here's a sample project demonstrating the issue: http://d.pr/f/IS4SEF

Comment: Is it an issue on iPhoneX (it has wide color gamut too)? Can it be reproduced in simulators?

Comment: Can you link proper and bad result images?

Comment: @paiv This is an iPad-only app, and we also don't have an iPhone X, so not sure. I presume it wouldn't work. It can't be reproduced in simulator, only device. I just edited my question with a link to a sample project. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have neither, just wondering what might be the issue. I made a few changes in repo here https://github.com/paiv/MaskBugWideColorDisplays, this is what it looks like in sim: https://i.imgur.com/iEg8PBb.png Can you screenshot it on device?

Answer (score 2):

Updated after discussion:

The issue seems to be in handling of CFData.

```
CFDataCreateMutable(CFAllocatorRef allocator, CFIndex capacity)
```

The `capacity` parameter is "The maximum number of bytes that the CFData object can contain." We still have to handle length property, either by appending bytes, or

```
CFDataSetLength(pixels, imageWidth * imageHeight)
```

---

Original answer:

Try not using named colors, like `UIColor.black`. Compose colors from components instead. Mixed color spaces might not be handled properly by Core Graphics.

Comment: I've tried every variation of color creation I'm aware of, unfortunately no dice. Is there a specific form of creation that works?

Comment: Hey, @paiv. Guess what...you got it working for us. In your fork of the sample project, you added this line of code: https://github.com/paiv/MaskBugWideColorDisplays/blob/1f133ce49b326de4ba3b4937a7d778ae60d442da/MaskBugWideColorDisplays/MaskView.swift#L31

Comment: Since the other bounty expired, I opened a new one so I could award you. As luck would have it, the new bounty has to be more than the last, so you're getting double the previous one. Thank you for the help! If you wouldn't mind updating your answer so it reflects the correct solution, I'll award you the bounty!